# remove time from getdate() using SQL

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, datetime

I was wondering if anyone new how to remove the time hh,mm,ss from the getdate? I am very new to using SQL and am having trouble. Right now I have the date added so it could always pull the current date and add one day to that. Now I need to remove the time from being shown completely. I do NOT want to change time to 00:00:00, I want it to be completely hidden.

Here is my code:

```
Select DATEADD(DAY, 1, GETDATE())
```

Comment: sql server? - CAST() the result to DATE

Answer (score 3):

Use [`CAST` or `CONVERT`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pl-pl/library/ms187928(v=sql.110).aspx).

Using `CAST`

```
SELECT DATEADD(DAY,1,CAST(GETDATE() as date))
```

Using `CONVERT`

```
SELECT DATEADD(DAY,1,CONVERT(date,GETDATE()))
```

Comment: If you give 2 answers, then give 2 examples to justify your answer.

Comment: @WEI_DBA you are right. I've edited answer. Thanks.